# Set LD_PRELOAD when executing a command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to execute a command like this: "`LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/so ./a.out`"

so I wrote a shell script:

```
cmd="LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/so ./a.out"
${cmd}
```

Error occured:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/so : no such file or directory
```

By the way, the file `/path/to/my/so` exists and I can successfully execute the command in a bash.

Anything wrong?

Comment: do you have the path right to your `.so`?

Comment: I can successfully execute the command by just in a bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be more traditional to just do something like this in your script:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=whatever
./a.out
```

Answer (score 3):

It's looking for an executable called `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/so` in your path and can't find it. You can use `eval` to get around this:

```
eval $CMD
```

Or, equivalently:

```
bash -c "$CMD"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There are several stages in bash command processing. At the very first stage variable assignment and redirections are identified and set aside for further processing. The rest of the command is then passed to the second stage. Variable expansion, along with other things, occurs at that stage.

Words like `FOO=bar` that result from the second stage are no longer interpreted as variable assignments.

If you want to compress a command with variable assignments and/or redirections into a single word, I recommend writing a function.